# Laravel post data with Ajax to Controller action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 controller in route file for get data from Ajax. i want to get data from ajax and handle that in simple controller by post method

**unfortunately i get this error:**

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283: 

Method [sendSmsToUser] does not exist.
```

**controllers :**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('sendSmsToUser', 'NotificationsController@sendSmsToUser');
    Route::post('sendEmailToUser', 'NotificationsController@sendEmailToUser');
});
```

**NotificationsController:**

```
class NotificationsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function postSendSmsToUser(Request $request)
    {
        $info = User::find($request::input('user_id'));
        $send = SendSMS::sendSms($info->mobile_number, $request->input('message'));
        if ($send) {
            Log::info("sms successfull send to user id" + $request->input('user_id'));
            return true;
        } else {
            Log::emergency("sms dont send to user");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ajax Request:**

```
$('[id^="send_sms-"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var message = $('#sms_message-' + id[1]).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        encoding: "UTF-8",
        url: "{{ url('sendSmsToUser') }}",
        data: {user_id: id[1], message: message},
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The method in the controller is called `postSendSmsToUser` but the route is looking for `NotificationsController@sendSmsToUser` isn't it? Do they need to match?

Comment: This is likely confusion between the methods `Route::post()` and `Route::controller()` where the method `postSendEmailToUser()` would have responded to that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Route::post('sendSmsToUser', 'NotificationsController@sendSmsToUser');` is calling the function `sendSmsToUser` in your controller.  That method doesn't exist.  It should probably read:

`Route::post('sendSmsToUser', 'NotificationsController@postSendSmsToUser');`